# How to change dbContext database name from Cookies/Session

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, database-connection, dbcontext

I have multiple user with their own database same schema, therefore we store their ConnectionString in cookie/session which solution will be available.

How can I use HttpContext. Cookies/Session data to change Connection String of DBContext by Per Request?

> DB Context

```
public MyContext(string ConnectionString) : base(ConnectionString)
{

}
```

> DependencyRegistrar

```
  public virtual void Register(ContainerBuilder builder, ITypeFinder typeFinder)
    {
    //data layer
        var dataSettingsManager = new DataSettingsManager();
        var dataProviderSettings = dataSettingsManager.LoadSettings();
        builder.Register(c => dataSettingsManager.LoadSettings()).As<DataSettings>();
        builder.Register(x => new EfDataProviderManager(x.Resolve<DataSettings>())).As<BaseDataProviderManager>().InstancePerDependency();

        builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<BaseDataProviderManager>().LoadDataProvider()).As<IDataProvider>().InstancePerDependency();

        if (dataProviderSettings != null && dataProviderSettings.IsValid())
        {
            var efDataProviderManager = new EfDataProviderManager(dataSettingsManager.LoadSettings());
            var dataProvider = efDataProviderManager.LoadDataProvider();
            dataProvider.InitConnectionFactory();

            builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new DBObjectContext(dataProviderSettings.DataConnectionString)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
        else
            builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new DBObjectContext(dataSettingsManager.LoadSettings().DataConnectionString)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        //repositories
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Comment: First of all storing of the `ConnectionString` in Cookie is very insecure. Cookies can be accessed via HttpContext. Are you using any Dependency Injection? (Microsoft DI, Autofac, SimpleInjector, NInject?) I would expect there code reading the cookie needs to be added.

Comment: @madoxdev I understand that Cookie is very insecure, I looking for session option but for solution of my problem I can use cookies also and it will be encrypted. Yes I am using Dependency Injection Microsoft DI, Autofac both. Do you have any solution.

Comment: Could you post the code that you use to register the dbcontext (add entity framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace:

from here:
`dataProviderSettings.DataConnectionString`

`builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new DBObjectContext(dataProviderSettings.DataConnectionString)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();`

with a class that will read the value from the cookie.

That new class wouldn't obviously be controller, so access to the `HttpContext` needs to be achieved via: `IHttpContextAccessor`.

To do so please add following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     //other registrations
     services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

Then in your new class:

```
    public class ConnectionStringAccessor {
        private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
        public ConnectionStringAccessor(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }

        public string GetConnectionString() {
            return  _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cookieName"].Value;
//you can consider some encryption/decryption or whatever you need to.
        }
    }
```

and then finally:

```
builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new DBObjectContext(c.Resolve<ConnectionStringAccessor >().GetConnecionString()).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I don't have VisualStudio available at the moment, so I put the code without building or testing. Also, your new class must be registered in DI.

For more information please refer to this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Just to reinforce, as I said in the comment, that way of dealing with sensible things like connection string is highly insecure.